# Is single-peaked preferences necessary for majority rule to be transitive and yield non-empty choice set?

Tags: social-choice

I understand that when individuals have single-peaked preferences, majority rule will be transitive and the choice set will be non-empty. So single peaked preferences is a sufficient condition.

Is it also necessary? If not, what other domain restriction can given majority rule a non empty choice set?

Answer (score 2):

No, single-peakedness is not necessary for majority rule to be transitive.  For example, "single-dipped" preference profiles (the vertical mirror image of "single-peaked" profiles) also produce transitive majority preferences.   A much-more general condition is "triple-wise value restriction", which Sen (1966) showed generates a transitive majority preference relation.  Here is a good summary of these and related concepts, with some references to the primary literature:

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/social-choice/#NonDicPreAggRul